# Why do such a birational map exists? And why it is unique?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, birational-geometry

Let $G$ be a complex linear algebraic group which is connected and reductive and let $\mathfrak g$ be its Lie algebra.
Suppose that $H \subset G$ is a 1-dimensional torus such that

1. the action of $H$ on $\mathfrak g$ produces a short grading, that is
   $
   \mathfrak g=\mathfrak g_{-1} \oplus \mathfrak g_0 \oplus \mathfrak g_1
   $.
2. there exists $n \in G$ such that $nhn^{-1}=h^{-1} \in H$.

Let $P,P^- \subset G$ be parabolic subgroups such that we have
$$
\mathfrak p= \mathfrak g_0 \oplus \mathfrak g_1 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathfrak p^-=\mathfrak g_{-1} \oplus \mathfrak g_0.
$$
Also we denote by $V,V^-$ the unipotent radical of $P,P^-$, respectively. Hence the Lie algebra of $V,V^-$ are, respectively, $\mathfrak g_1, \mathfrak g_{-1}$. It follows by 2. that
$$
P^-=nPn^{-1} \quad \text{and} \quad V^-=nVn^{-1}.
$$
Then $P,P^-$ are opposite parabolic subgroups in the sense of Borel (Groupes Reductifs) and there is a birational map
$$
V \times P^- \dashrightarrow G
$$
given by the product
$$
(x,npn^{-1}) \mapsto x \cdot npn^{-1}.
$$
In its book (Jordan algebras and algebraic groups, page 34), Springer says that from this product map it follows that there is unique birational map $j: V \dashrightarrow V$ such that
$$
j(x) \cdot nxn^{-1} \in P^- \subset G
$$
if $j(x)$ is defined.

I do not understand both existence and uniqueness of such a map $j$. Moreover, I would like to understand how this map should be obtained. Any idea or suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: A few small notes: Firstly the opposite parabolic bit doesn't depend on condition 2, it is from the grading that we have that (your grading is even more restrictive than that in the springer book in fact and implies that $V,V^-$ are abelian). Secondly Springer asserts that $V^-\cdot P$ and $VnP$ are both open in $G$ and thus there is a birational map between them and from that he defines $j$ such that $j(x) \cdot nxn^{-1} \in nP$ which is a bit different to what you have written I think.